# Setting a file folder to function like a desktop W8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, desktop, user-folders

Windows 8.1
I always end up making my desktop the file folder for my projects and their assets. I do this because it saves time since the desktop is always the bottom of all open applications and easy to access and I can actually move things around as I please unlike in a folder in windows. That said when a project is done its laying around the desktop and time is wasted finding and reorganizing things.

I was wondering if I could somehow create a folder and make it function like my desktop while im working on my project. then when I'm done working on it I just close the folder and there's no mess to cleanup...and it goes back to my original desktop

In the simplest of forms I guess I'm looking for a screen that overlays just the desktop. The functionality of a grid type system (what the desktop functions as) so I can move things around, or at least have them appear in a grid like system, would be good too.

Comment: What kind of projects? If coding, your IDE will always show you all files in the project.

Comment: Do you work on multiple projects (very messy desktop)? If a single project, when it is finished., move all from desktop to a backup folder & start your new project. You could even switch projects by moving the entire contents of directories around..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual Desktops are the best solution apparently, for lack of a better one.